# Tackle Localization with Graphql

Tags: localization, graphql

In a json file, I have some fields that have a list of dictionaries with the locale and the translated text:

```
description_localized: [
  {
      locale: "en-UK",
      value: "Read along"
   },
 {
       locale: "de-DE",
       value: "Lesen und"
   },
 {
        locale: "fr-FR",
        value: "Lis avec"
    },
]
```

There are other fields where there are two keys in the value key:

```
path_localized: [
    {
        locale: "de-DE",
        value: "{"identifier"=>"", "value"=>"http://path_6987.path"}"
    },
    {
        locale: "es-ES",
        value: "{"identifier"=>"", "value"=>"http://path_4685.path"}"
    },
```

I already created a schema that grabs these fields, but instead of pulling the entire dictionary, on Graphql, I will need to be able to make a query where I only specify the language-locale I want (e.g. fr-FR) and that would only fetch the translated value for that one language (fr-FR). I don't want to get an array of all localized languages as this will be very taxing and will take longer to load per query.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could accomplish this? Maybe through a resolver where I pass in the language as a parameter? But where would the languages be defined? I may need to clean this but we have an assortment of locale definitions: en_UK, en-UK, UK, en_UK_CO... Also, if the queried language is not found, how could I define a fallback?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What stack are you working on, Node.js? If so, you can find a localization example here: https://github.com/kriasoft/nodejs-api-starter ..it uses "i18next" module to detect user's language, fallback to default language etc. then you can pass "lng" string as a context variable and use that inside of your "resolve()" methods. See `src/app.js`, `src/Context.js`.

Comment: I'm using Python with Flask.